# Как получить трансформации относительно самого объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

`transform.localePosition`,`transform.localeRotation`, `transform.localeScale` - трансформация объекта относительно родителя, а как получить трансформации относительно самого объекта?

Comment: ```transform.position```

Comment: Позиция объекта `относительно его самого` вообще равна (0,0,0). То, что вы (наверное) хотите называется позиция/вращение/размер относительно глобальных координат. Помимо `transform.position`, указанного @Mr.AntonDer, есть `transform.rotation` и `transform.lossyScale`. И это легко гуглится за пару... А в общем не важно...